# call multiple functions as assigned variables

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement
test1.py:
function1
function2

test2.py
function3
function4

I have a file defined with function names.
test.txt:
function1
function2
function3
function4

my requirement is to call the function names from test.txt and execute them

my requirement is to call the function names from test.txt and execute them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

test.txt

```
func1
func2
func3
func4
```

test2.py

```
def func3():
    print("func3")

def func4():
    print("func4")
```

test1.py

```
from test2 import func3, func4

def func1():
     print("func1")

def func2():
     print("func2")

with open("test.txt", 'rt', encoding='utf8') as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        function_name = line.strip()
        function = globals()[function_name]
        function()
```

Just import the required functions from second python module individually so the function name becomes part of the global namespace, then read in the file one line at a time and execute the appropriate function by using the line as the key in the `globals()` function.

Expected Output:

```
func1
func2
func3
func4
```

Comment: Your welcome, you can click the checkbox to mark it as the correct answer